# Finding the range of the function $y = f(x) = \ln \frac {a+x}{a-x} , a > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So , I was told to find the domain and range of the function below:

> $$y = f(x) = \ln \frac {a+x}{a-x} , a > 0$$

The domain of $f$ is $(-a,a)$. I understood the solution for the domain . My problem was with understanding the solution for the range.

And Here is the solution of the book for the range:

$$y = f(x) = \ln \frac {a+x}{a-x} , a > 0$$
$$\to e^y = \frac {a+x}{a-x}$$
$$\to a+x = ae^y - xe^y$$
$$\to x + xe^y = ae^y - a$$
$$\to (1 + e^y)x = a(e^y - 1)$$
$$\to x = \frac {a(e^y - 1)}{e^y + 1}$$

for all real values of $y$ , $x$ is also real. So ,  $R_f = \mathbb {R}$ (Here $R_f$ means "the range of $f$")

What I did not understood here is that , when we are trying to find the range , aren't we supposed to find what are all possible values of $y = f(x)$ we will get for every $x \in D_f$ ? The solution in the book feels like the opposite. Can someone tell me what I am missing here in my understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is that, from the expression of $x$ obtained in terms of $y$, it is clear that if you plug in any real value of $y$, a corresponding real value for $x$ will always be obtained. Since the function obtained in $y$ is inverse of the original function, this means that if you plug in the obtained value of $x$ into the original function, you would get back the value of $y$ that you started with, because $$f(f^{-1}(x))=x$$

Now since all real $y$ give some $x$, this means that range will be the set of all real numbers.